# text over an image in the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have a text that should be placed over the image. Now the image covers the text, any text that is not visible. I thought here is what the priorities for the display, but did not find them. Tell me how you can specify that the text should be drawn over the picture, and not vice versa.

[image]

[image]

debug view
[image]

Comment: Try to move the image above the text field on your heirarchy, else remove the text label from the heirarchy and again put it on image!!!

Comment: @Mr.T It is impossible, the picture still is placed on top of the text.

Comment: try bringing subview to the front with [parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];

Comment: try removing the leading constraint or centre constraint for your label

Comment: Wait... which is the real screenshot. In your latest edit the screenshot with the labels above the image view will put the labels behind. They were fine where they were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order that things appear in the navigation bar (the second screenshot) is the order they draw in. The lower down they are the later they are drawn. So at the moment your image view will be behind you text (and everything else).

That's actually what it shows in the Interface Builder also as you can see the text.

TBH, your AutoLayout constraints look a little suspect to me. I suspect they are pushing the label off the screen. I really don't think you want the constraints that way. You don't need a height to begin with and if you want the label centred then give it a centre constraint not a leading constraint.

What, exactly, is giving you the impression that the image is over your text? Have you tried the view debugger in the simulator?

Comment: YEs, you are correct. LEading margin +71 should be the culprit!!! Either the OP should remove leading constraint or centre.X constraint

Comment: I updated photo. It seems to me that it is the text of the back, because I do not see it in the logs and not given any mistakes with beaten restrictions. I changed the hierarchy changed limitations, but I can not find the answer (

Comment: Use the View Debugger in Xcode. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html Just because you cannot see the text does not mean it is behind the image. The view debugger will give you a 3D view of the screen so you can find where the text is. I suspect the constraints are pushing it off screen.

Comment: I saw that the text is drawn back.

Comment: @user2759544 yes, because in your latest edit you moved them to behind the image view. Put them back to how they were. They need to be underneath the image view in the hierarchy.

Comment: I corrected, restored as it was before. can you tell where to look mistake I simply can not understand.

Comment: Look at the link I posted. When running the app there is a button that you press that will show the view debugger. You need to see where the views actually are. It is all explained in the link I posted.  @user2759544

Comment: i uploaded photo. it shows that the text is behind the image and drag up his?

Comment: @user2759544 then you are changing something in code. We have very little information to go on here. Tell us EVERYTHING. Then we might be able to work out what's going on.

Comment: @user2759544 hi again. I have noticed this happening to me now. The view hierarchy in InterfaceBuilder does not match the view hierarchy in the app. Several times I have had to shuffle the views around and back to the same order they started in order to get views to show in the correct order. Looks like an Xcode bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can call bringSubviewToFront method in code `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.label];`

Comment: From the Interface Builder navigator the text is already in front of the image.

Answer (score -1):

I found solution - mode = Aspect Fit

Comment: I'm sorry to say but that's absolute rubbish. Like I explained in the comments of my answer (just a few hours ago) it appears there is a bug in Interface Builder. `mode = Aspect Fit` is nothing to do with the text or image being on top. It is to do with how the image is resized and cropped. I have found that sometimes the order shown by Interface Builder is not correct. Shuffling the views around fixes it.

Comment: In the same way as shuffling views around might fix the bug also changing properties like the content mode may also fix the bug. The mode is nothing to do with what is being fixed though.

Comment: @Fogmeister sorry I like your answer